# Find world matrix

Tags: c#, 3d, xna-4.0, matrix, monogame

I'm making my first 3D-game with XNA (MonoGame) and have come to a point where I wish to add a crosshair for the player. To do this I need the on-screen coordinates of the location where my fighter would actually fire. However, I've run into some problems with this, mainly in finding my world matrix...

When drawing, I use the following snippet:

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();

                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index]
                     * Matrix.CreateRotationX(angle.X)
                     * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle.Y)
                     * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(angle.Z)
                     * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);

                effect.View = camera.ViewMatrix;

                effect.Projection = camera.Projection;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
```

My understanding is that to be able to get my 2D screen coordinates, I need to use
something like this:

```
//Yes, this currently returns a Vector3 and probably looks horrible on line 2 but I have not yet had any ouput to test this with
Vector3 temp = Game1.game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject(Fighter.player.Position + Fighter.player.Forward * 50, Camera3D.camera.Projection, Camera3D.camera.ViewMatrix, Matrix.Identity);
Position = new Vector2(temp.X, temp.Y);
```

Which requires the world transform as the final argument. Since my effect.world changes with each BasicEffect (7 of them) I can't really get a hold on what my World Matrix is.

Any help?

**EDIT**

In my case I was able to use the code I used above with the only change that instead of Viewport.Unproject I used Viewport.Project.

I'm still not sure how to get the world matrix when it's set with variables that can vary (such as transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index]) and am still intrested in this. My specific problem however was solvable by simply using Matrix.Identity as world matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get 2d screen coordinates from a 3d world space location, you would use `Viewport.Project`, not `Viewport.Unproject`.

The world matrix to put in the `Project` method would be the same one you use to set the `effect.World` property for rendering.

Comment: Yes, well the problem is that my effect.world uses transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] and therefore is not really extractable, hence my question.

Comment: Yes it is, give the transforms class scope, then instead of setting their values them in the `Draw()` method, set the transforms values in the `Update()` method after moving or rotating the object then simply use them in the Project and later use them in the `Draw()` method for the `effect.World`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see your point. Cant believe I missed that.

Comment: It's been a few months, here is a more accurate response:  Yes it is, give the transforms class scope, then instead of setting their values them in the `Draw()` method, set the transforms values in the `LoadContent()` method after loading the model, then simply use them in the Project and later use them in the `Draw()` method for the `effect.World`.

Comment: Do it in the LoadContent because your really ever only need to set those transforms once, not every frame like the Update would do.